# When click another application my application automatically destroyed?

Tags: android, ondestroy

My application is running in the same time i can select another application, my application is destroyed automatically. How do avoid destroy.

Comment: How exactly you select another application ?

Comment: Use tag for the activity in manifest android:alwaysRetainTaskState and study from the link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always

Comment: Can you explain your problem in detail

Comment: @ShishirShetty `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog"` So my application is a dialog format. So i am easily select any application.

Comment: @nick `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog"` i am using my window as a dialog format. So i can easily select any one application. When i select another appplication my application is automatically destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary, the app is destroyed only if the app is finished or the OS needs the resources.
[This page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) explains it better with a state diagram that shows the life cycle of an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that when you switch applications in android and want yours to run on the background?

The idea in android is that when you "close" your application, its not actually closed, its moved to the background and the onPause(), onStop() and onDestroy functions are called. These are the callbacks taht you can use to handle the way your application stays running. See the following link on how to handle android activity life cycles:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

One way to make a part of your application to run on background is to run the part of it that you want to run in a separate thread in the activity. For example in one of my apps we have a bluetooth receiver running in a thread() that I start in the onCreate() function. Then when I exit the application, in onDestroy() I have a specific list of if calls to kill the thread when you really want to kill the application, but otherwise it's left to run in the background.

The concept of leaving an app running and how to implement it depends a lot on your specific thing that you're trying to accomplish and I can't really give you a good answer based on the infromation you provided.